# Is the current version of Phantom omni device (Geomagic Touch) compatible with ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am wondering if the current version of the PHANToM Omni device (the Geomagic Touch http://www.geomagic.com/en/products/phantom-omni/overview) is compatible with ROS or not.

Actually, i am going to buy one of them and i want to be sure that it is compatible with ROS.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226811/is-the-current-version-of-phantom-omni-device-(geomagic-touch)-compatible-with-ros?/) by [masihec](https://answers.ros.org/users/24631/masihec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [masihec](https://answers.ros.org/users/24631/masihec/) on 2016-02-17**:
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all make sure it is compatible with modern Linux distributions. Even before SensAble was acquired by Geomagic there were a lot of problems with their proprietary drivers. If it is the same hardware and same drivers then there are couple of ROS packages that might work with it.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1